# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of null : conflct

Tags: jquery

I wrote this code to create a floating sidebar that sticks at top of the browser window.  I am getting this error in chrome in line 3.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of null
```

this is causing a plugin I am using not to work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Floating sidebars on page nodes
    var sidebartop = $('.page-node .panels-flexible-region-node_layout-right').offset().top;
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if( $(window).scrollTop() > sidebartop ) {
            $('.page-node .panels-flexible-region-node_layout-right').css({position: 'fixed', top: '40px', margin: '0 0 0 650px'});
        } else {
            $('.page-node .panels-flexible-region-node_layout-right').css({position: 'static', margin: '-35px 0 0 0'});
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that `$('.page-node .panels-flexible-region-node_layout-right')` exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, jQuery couldn't find specified selector. I'am right if

```
$('.page-node .panels-flexible-region-node_layout-right')
```

returns empty array. Try to set some id for your sidebar (or which element you want to get offset) and rewrite code like

```
var sidebartop = $('#your-selector-id').offset().top;
```

Also, you can search difference between `.first-class .second-class` and `.first-class.second-class` (note for lack of space in second example) query rules.